# Where X Client process be running if executed on remote host?

Tags: linux, unix, xorg, x-server, thin-client

If I am to run X server on my 'local' machine and ssh to a 'remote' machine with X-forwarding enabled, and then execute an X client (say web browser) in that 'remote' machine, where will my browser process actually be running?

Also is it possible to install X clients on a headless, X-server-less host?

Answer (score 0):

The X client will be running on the host where you start it. So if you execute an X client on the 'remote' machine, it will run on the 'remote' machine, and communicate with the 'local' X server over the network. It's not somehow magically migrated to the 'local' machine.

You can run an X client anywhere as long as it can connect to an X server, either remotely, or over the network. So yes, you can run X clients on a headless, X-server-less host (but it will need the X client libraries).

Which X server an X client connects to depends on the `DISPLAY` variable, or the command line options (often `-display`). So you can run on the same host (a) an X client that connects to one locally running X server, (b) another X client that connects to another, different locally running X server, with a different monitor and keyboard, (c) an X client that connects to a remote X server.

Comment: is there any shortcomings of this approach (x client talks to x server over ssh x forwarding) to fill a thin client requirements for small a group of users (say 5 users) over LAN? WANs? the Internet?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. A remote connection between an X server and an X client will always be slower than both of them running on the same machine. Over WAN it will be very noticably slower (I've done this via modem over 200 km telephone line, it can be done, but it's no phone). Also, many modern X programs actually require OpenGL or similar, which is not network transparent (though there are attempts at solutions for that, too). So it very much depends on what clients you plan to run.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your `$DISPLAY` environment

Yes, of course you can use x clients on headless server - this is one of primary goals of X client-server design.